# Efficiently attach a partition to a table with a foreign key to a partitioned table in PostgreSQL on Google Cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, database-partitioning

**Context**

PostgreSQL Version: 13.7

Hosting: Google Cloud SQL

**Situation**

I have 2 partitioned tables where table A has a foreign key to table B. By the nature of how table partitioning works, the foreign keys on table A partitions all point to the parent table B. In practice, I have one tenant id per partition, so it would be optimal to have a partition of table A have a direct foreign key to the partition for the same tenant on table B, but that is undestandably not facilitated by table partitioning.

When I attach an empty table as a partition to table B, the operation is really quick. When I attach a partition to table A, it takes forever. Upon investigating, I found that the operation is creating thousands of locks across all of the partitions for table B due to the foreign key referencing the parent table B. I believe this is occurring because when the table becomes a partition of table A it is inheriting a foreign key to table B and runs a check across all of its partitions (even though the new partition is empty). When I remove the foreign key, the operation is very fast.

**Problem**

I assume that disabling the foreign key constraints would make the attach operation quick. Unfortunately, since I am using Google Cloud SQL, I can't disable the foreign keys since they don't grant me superuser privileges. One option I can see is to remove the foreign key from the parent table and add it back after the operation. I don't love this option for many reasons (maintainability, data integrity, sanity, ...). There is also the option of simply not using foreign keys which I also don't love.

This isn't just an issue of speed. The mass locking creates contention in the db that prevents other ambient operations that a user might be performing at the time of the partition attaching.

**Question**

Are there any other options that I can explore to reduce the amount of locking that is occurring when attaching a partition to a table that has a foreign key to a partitioned table?